# How do I reload an ASP page with a new querystring?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, query-string

In VBScript I'm getting an error every time I run this code. I just want to reload the page if the "p" variable can't be found in the `querystring`.

What am I doing wrong exactly?

```
Dim sURL            'URL of the document
sURL = document.URL

'Set page number equal to 1
If( InStr( sUrl, "?" ) = 0 ) Then
    sURL = sURL & "?p=1"
    window.location = sURL
    window.location.reload()
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

What are you doing wrong? It looks like almost everything. Your code looks like mess of VBS and JavaScript.

What you need is

```
<%@LANGUAGE=VBSCRIPT%>
<%
    If Request.QueryString("p") = "" Then
        Response.Redirect Request.ServerVariables("URL") & "?p=1"
    Else
        Response.Write "YES! WE HAVE IT!"
    End If
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 If( InStr( sUrl, "?" ) = 0 ) Then
    sURL = sURL & "?p=1"
   window.location.href =  sURL & "?p=1"
 End If
```

Comment: The question was tagged vbscript, but you have given a JavaScript answer.  As pointed out in the other solution, the original question max mixing the two.

Comment: This is pretty clearly _not a JavaScript answer_ (`End If` is VB, not JS). While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: It certainly looks like VBS, but `window.location` suggests that it's client side code.  Client side VBS is something separate from ASP, (and it's only supported by Internet Explorer)

Comment: @John is 100% right this is client side VBScript and it is supported by IE only, but few companies are still using it in corporate intranets (controlled environment)

Answer (score 0):

Why bother?  You're simply assuming a default, therefore when you process your page and look up the `p` QueryString value just set it to the default if there's not a matching value...

```
Dim p
p = Request.QueryString("p")
If "" & p = "" Then p = 1
```

No need for any page reloads.

To take this a stage further I tend to use a function like this...

```
'GetPostData
'   Obtains the specified data item from the previous form get or post.
'Usage:
'   thisData = GetPostData("itemName", "Alternaitve Value")
'Parameters:
'   dataItem (string) - The data item name that is required.
'   nullVal (variant) - The alternative value if the field is empty.
'Description:
'   This function will obtain the form data irrespective of type (i.e. whether it's a post or a get).
'Revision info:
'   v0.2 -      Function has been renamed to avoid confusion.
'   v0.1.2 -    Inherent bug caused empty values not to be recognised.
'   v0.1.1 -    Converted the dataItem to a string just in case.
function GetPostData(ByVal dataItem, ByVal nullVal)
    dim rV
    'Check the form object to see if it contains any data...
    if request.Form("" & dataItem) = "" then
        if request.QueryString("" & dataItem)="" then 
            rV = CStr(nullVal)
        else
            rV = request.QueryString("" & dataItem)
        end if
    else
        rV = request.Form("" & dataItem)
    end if
    'Return the value...
    GetPostData = rV
end function
```

...to keep my code tidy. The function simply returns a default if the posted data is missing. Note that this function will actually check for both QueryString and Form data before returning the default.